# Log Issue on Dontnet Framework application when application deploy on windows container

Tags: dockerfile

I create one application in the Dotnet Framework WEBAPI. I used to container service to deploy this application, I used two dotnet framework container one for build one for rum. (dotnet/framework/sdk) use to create build and (dotnet/framework/aspnet) use to deploy. Application deploy successfully, when hit api give response correct but log not generated. IN the local system we use visuale studio 2019 to run application then log generated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9tog.png)